# show category level in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Let say I have product under `parent->child one` and another product under `parent->child one->child one child` all i can get is last category name like:
`child one` and `child one child` but parent names before them i cannot get.

## Code

**Category model:**

```
public function categories()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
  }
  public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'category_id','id') ;
  }
public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
```

**Product model:**

```
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
```

And I store category id in products table, column named `category_id`.
PS: in this column i store last category id, like if i have:

`parent->child one` i store `child one` id in there.

## UPDATE

Base on answers I've made some changes in my category model and by code below I've tried to get my product category levels:

```
@if($product->category->isParent())
  {{ucfirst($product->category->title)}} </br>
@else 
  {{ucfirst($product->category->parent->title)}} >  {{ucfirst($product->category->title)}}  </br>
@endif
```

### Issue

Issue by code above is: if my product is in third level (or more) I only get parent of last category and not all the way top. `EXAMPLE`

my product is in : `Laptop->HP->PAVILION` all I get is `HP->PAVILION` cannot get `laptop` category.

Comment: Don't you store category level?

Comment: @Sakezzz nope!.

Comment: Relational databases are not the best when it comes to hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand good but...

Into `Category` Model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
}
public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
public function isParent() 
{
    return !$this->category_id ? true : false; // if category_id is null => is a Parent Category
}
```

You can do `$category->isParent()` to know if is a Parent or not.

- If **is** parent category you can do `$category->childs` to get all sub categories.
- If **is not** a parent you can do `$category->parent` to get parent Category.

Comment: `isParent` here in reality is `isRoot` since a category can be a parent and itself have its own parent .

Comment: Yes, I think that is reality is `isRoot`. Thanks

Comment: hi thanks for the answer as my first question, should i remove my `categories` function in my category model?

Comment: I think that yes, but you can use the method name you want.  If you want you could replace `childs()` to `categories()` . The name is not important. The important thing is the concept of you are doing.

Comment: ok, so how do i show it in my products page? `$product->category`? `$product->childs` etc.?

Comment: @MaruAmallo Updated my question, please check it.

Comment: didn't get a thing from your link! :/

Comment: well? any more help?

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you are defining wrong relationships between the classes. Please refer this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many laravel documentation for the same.

Also if you want to call a particular child through a parent model, one way to call is as below:

```
$children = App\Category::find(1)->childs;
```

Because you have defined your relationship function with name "childs" you have to use same name to access the children for that class.